# how to make alerts appear if the number of infant is more than adults

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to make the alert appear if the number of infant is more than adults.
I've tried but it looks like something went wrong.
Please help.. thanks before

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/pBxfX/132/

```
var button = $('#submit'),
    adult = $('#adult option:selected').val(),
    infant = $('#infant option:selected').val();

if(adult > infant) {
 $("#alert").hide;
}
else if(adult == infant) {
 $("#alert").hide;
} 
else {
 $("#alert").show;
}
```

Comment: try to use `$('select').change(function(){ } ` instead of code like that.. i will post an answer after this

Comment: Uhhh maybe you should call functions?  `$("#alert").show` will do nothing,  `$("#alert").show();` might do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You need to treat hide and show as methods (call them as .hide() and .show())
2. You need to execute your checking code in the *change* event handler for the select.
3. When comparing adults to infants, you need to treat them as integers (they are currently being treated as strings).

See http://jsfiddle.net/pBxfX/133/ for updated code

```
var button = $('#submit');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(button).attr('disabled', true);
    $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
        var from = $("#from").val(),
            to = $("#to").val();
        if (from != '' && to != '') {
            $(button).attr('disabled', false);

        } else {
            $(button).attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    // Run code when any <select> changes
    $("select").on('change', function() {
        var adult = parseInt($('#adult option:selected').val()); //convert to integers for comparison
        var infant = parseInt($('#infant option:selected').val());  //convert to integers for comparison
        if (adult > infant) {
            $("#alert").hide(); //Note that it is .hide() not .hide
        } else if (adult == infant) {
            $("#alert").hide();
        } else {
            $("#alert").show();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. next time i will be more thorough again
http://jsfiddle.net/pBxfX/137/

Answer (score 1):

`hide()` and `show()` are `functions` so you need to add `()` to call these functions.

```
if(adult > infant) {
 $("#alert").hide();
}
else if(adult == infant) {
 $("#alert").hide();
} 
else {
 $("#alert").show();
}
```